# Visual Basic: Set attribute of web element whitout ID

Tags: vba, element

HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="79" value="" name="username">
```

As you can see, no ID. The HTML above is a textbox that i want to auto fill in whit my value as soon as i start the webpage whit my code.

this is what i found:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("username")(0).SetAttribute("value", (Text))
```

But whit this i get the error:

```
Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
Parameter name: index
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing (0) after "username".  Your tags for this question should include javascript at the very least.  Also, it's WITH, not whit.

Comment: @user652411: I don't think this is using JavaScript.  It looks like `WebBrowser1` is a VB object, which has members to mimic JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to find any elements:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("username")
```

"Tag name" doesn't mean the value of the `name` attribute, it means the name of the HTML tag itself.  Like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("input")
```

Of course, this is likely to return multiple matched elements, so you'll need to further identify which one you want to modify.  The point being that you should do some error checking to make sure that it finds anything, because trying to index an empty collection will result in an error:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("username")(0)
```

Since the collection has no elements, there is nothing at index `0`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that its not possible? or am i missing something here.

Comment: @user2819294: I'm not saying that at all.  I'm saying that in order to get elements by tag name you have to supply the tag name (`input`), not the value of the `name` attribute.  You'll then get back a collection of all elements of that tag name, and in that collection you can find the one you're looking for and set the attribute you're trying to set.

Comment: I really cant figure this out, perhaps you can give me an example. Could you by any chance auto fill in the "email" field on facebook.com whitout useing the ID value?

Comment: @user2819294: Of course.  All you need to do is identify that element in the DOM.  Once you've singled it out, you can modify it any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

May be u could try

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByName("username").SetAttribute("Value", txtUsername.Text)
```